# Solving Poisson Equation with domain $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash \{ 0 \})$.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, operator-theory

I want to solve the following equation $$\Delta u \pm i u =0,$$ where $u \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3\backslash \{ 0 \})$ is a smooth function, compactly supported away from the origin. Note that this is an attempt to determine the deficiency indices of the operator $-\Delta $. I can use the Fourier transform, this gives me $$(\left|\xi \right|^2 \pm i)\hat{u} =0.$$ It is possible to treat $u$ as a $\delta$-function? 
I'm unsure.

Answer (score 0):

If you define $Lf=-\Delta f$ on $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\})$, then $L$ is symmetric on its domain $\mathcal{D}(L)$, and the domain is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$. The deficiency spaces are associated with the adjoint operator $L^*$. So you're looking for functions $f \in L^2$ such that
$$
       \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \{(L\pm iI)g\}\overline{f} dx = 0,\;\;\; g\in\mathcal{D}(L).
$$
Any such $f$ is going to be an $L^2$ weak solution of $(-\Delta\mp iI)g=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$. And, it would admit solutions of the form you stated, assuming such functions are in $L^2$.

There are radial solutions of your equations, which are the solutions of the following for any given complex $\lambda$:
$$
       Lf(r) = -\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r^2\frac{df}{dr}\right)= \lambda f.
$$
There is a simplication when substituting $f=\frac{1}{r}g$. The new equation is
$$
     -\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r^2\left(\frac{1}{r}\frac{dg}{dr}-\frac{1}{r^2}g\right)\right)=\frac{\lambda}{r}g \\
      -\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{dg}{dr}-g\right)=\lambda rg \\
    -r\frac{d^2g}{dr^2}-\frac{dg}{dr}+\frac{dg}{dr}=\lambda rg \\
     \frac{d^2g}{dr^2}+\lambda g = 0.
$$
The solutions are
$$
           f(r)=\frac{g}{r} = A\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}r)}{r}+B\frac{\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}r)}{r} \\
     = A'\frac{e^{i\sqrt{\lambda}r}}{r}+B'\frac{e^{-i\sqrt{\lambda}r}}{r}.
$$
The second forms are better because exponential decay puts the solution in $L^2_{r^2}[0,\infty)$. Boundary functionals are the real and imaginary parts of
$$
          \Phi(f) = (Lf,f_{i})-(f,Lf_{i}) .
$$

Comment: Yes, I understand this, I'm not sure how to get an explicit form for the solution of $(\left| \xi \right|^2 \pm i)\hat{u} =0$. How does this give us the dimensions of the deficiency spaces, and hence allow us to classify the self-adjoint extensions of $-\Delta$?

Comment: @Elliot : The dimension of the space should be the number of linearly-independent conditions you can impose at $x=0$. What do you think that dimension is going to be?

Comment: @Elliot : Have you checked to see if there are radial solutions?

Comment: Wouldn't the number of linearly-independent conditions we can impose at $x=0$ be only one? I don't know how to prove that, my reasoning is that I can't think of more than one condition...

Comment: I'm not sure why we would consider radial solutions...?

Comment: @Elliot : The solutions are going to be associated with a condition at one point, which would certainly suggest radial solutions only, at least to me. One associated condition is going to be the value of the function at the origin. You already know that one because of the $\delta$ function connection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58550/discussion-between-elliot-and-disintegratingbyparts).

Comment: @Elliot : I posted more for you.