# Eigenvalues of self-adjoint extension of the Laplacian

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, laplacian

Consider the Laplace operator $-\Delta$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ with domain $C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash \{ 0 \})$, the smooth functions with compact support not near 0. I have had a look at this [Solving Poisson Equation with domain $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash \{ 0 \})$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2274210/solving-poisson-equation-with-domain-l2-mathbbr3-backslash-0/2275005?noredirect=1#comment4680959_2275005)

But feel that what was missing here was that since we are away from zero, we can't simply solve $(\Delta^{\ast} \pm i)u =0$, it is better to solve ($\Delta^{\ast} \pm i)u =\delta$ for some $\delta$ function. In so doing, taking the Fourier transform yields that $$(4\pi^2 \left| \xi \right|^2 \pm i) \hat{u}(\xi) = 1,$$ and therefore, $$u = \frac{1}{4\pi} \frac{e^{i\sqrt{\pm i} \ |x|}}{|x|}. $$

From this, I want to show that all self-adjoint extensions of $-\Delta$ have a negative eigenvalue, except possibly one. I'm fairly sure we need to use the above formula that I've obtained for $u$, but am unsure. Also, how would we obtain the Friedrich's extension from this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're solving an adjoint equation by looking for all $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ for which
$$
         \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\{(\Delta\mp i)\varphi\}\overline{f}dx =0, \;\;\; \varphi \in C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}).
$$
A function $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R^3})$ satisfies the above adjoint equation iff $f \in \mathcal{D}(\Delta^*\pm iI)$ with $(\Delta^*\pm iI)f=0$. Because the Laplacian is nice, weak solutions of this type are classical solutions in $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$. There are no non-trivial solutions $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ of
$$
      \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\{(\Delta\mp i)\varphi\}\overline{f}dx = 0,\;\;\;\varphi\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3).
$$
The classical solutions of $(\Delta - i)f_{+} = 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$ include radial solutions
$$
         \frac{e^{\pm \sqrt{i} r}}{r}=\frac{\exp(\pm(1+i)r/\sqrt{2})}{r}
$$
However, the only solution in $\mathcal{D}(\Delta^*)$ is the one that is in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\})$, which is
$$
              f_{+} = \frac{e^{-r/\sqrt{2}}e^{-ir/\sqrt{2}}}{r}.
$$
Conjugation gives $f_{-}$ that is a solution of $(\Delta+i)f_{-}=0$:
$$
              f_{-} = \frac{e^{-r/\sqrt{2}}e^{ir/\sqrt{2}}}{r}.
$$
There is a one-parameter family of selfadjoint extensions obtained by adding one element to the native domain of the form
$$
      h_{\lambda}=\frac{1}{r}e^{-r/\sqrt{2}}\{ e^{ir/\sqrt{2}}e^{i\alpha}-e^{-ir/\sqrt{2}}e^{-i\alpha} \} = C\frac{1}{r}e^{-r/\sqrt{2}}\sin(r/\sqrt{2}+\alpha).
$$
To check if there are negative eigenvalues, start by checking if $(-\Delta h_{\lambda},h_{\lambda})$ is negative. For example,
\begin{align}
    (\Delta h_{\lambda},h_{\lambda})&=(\Delta(e^{i\alpha}f_+-e^{-i\alpha}f_-),e^{i\alpha}f_+-e^{-i\alpha}f_+) \\
   &= i(e^{i\alpha}f_++e^{-i\alpha}f_-,e^{i\alpha}f_+-e^{-i\alpha}f_-) \\
   &= i\|f_+\|^2-i\|f_-\|^2+i(e^{-i\alpha}f_-,e^{i\alpha}f_+)-i(e^{i\alpha}f_+,e^{-i\alpha}f_-) \\
   &= 2\Im\{ e^{2i\alpha} (f_+,f_-)\}.
\end{align}

Comment: What do you mean by "native domain"?

Comment: @J.Doetry : The native domain of $-\Delta$, which is $C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\})$, though, it's better to start with the closure of this operator.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Also, with regard to the linked post, you make reference to the fact that the second form is better behaved since it puts the solutions in $L_{r^2}^2[0, \infty)$. Could you explain this, also defining what you mean by $L_{r^2}^2[0,\infty)$?

Comment: @J.Doetry : When considering radial solutions $f(r)$, they must be in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$, which, after a change of variables into spherical coordinates, translates to $f\in L^2_{r^2}[0,\infty)$, meaning $\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(r)|^2 r^2 dr < \infty$.

Comment: That makes sense, cheers

Comment: I've evaluated $(-\Delta h_{\lambda}, h_{\lambda}) = -\frac{c^2}{4\sqrt{2}}(e^{-\sqrt{2}r}(\sin(\sqrt{2}r+2\lambda)+\cos(\sqrt{2}r+2\lambda))$, which is only negative for sufficiently large $r$.

Comment: @J.Doetry : $(-\Delta h_{\lambda},h_{\lambda})=C\int_{0}^{\infty}(-\Delta h_{\lambda})h_{\lambda} r^2 dr$, $C> 0$. How do the integrals evaluate?

Comment: Formally, we have $C\int_0^{\infty} (-\Delta h_{\lambda})h_{\lambda}r^2dr = -C \int_0^{\infty} h_{\lambda}(\Delta h_{\lambda} + 2(h_{\lambda}+2r Dh_{\lambda})dr,$ which is given by integrating by parts. If one is to the computation explicitly, it becomes rather horrifying.

Comment: I'm still confused by how we actually go about your suggested computation

Comment: @J.Doetry :  I added a piece at the end for you to look at. Working abstractly is better.

Comment: Looking at this problem, how does the calculation of $(\Delta h_{\lambda},h_{\lambda})$ helps us show the that all but one self-adjoint extension has a negative eigenvalue?

Comment: @David : What have you found the minimum value of $(\Delta h_{\lambda},h_{\lambda})$ to be?